# PHP Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 (not on dev, but on stage)

Tags: php, iis, json, iconv, utf

I get the following error when I transfer my code to a stage env:  "PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8" I do not get this error on my development environment. I am fixing the issue with:

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $value);
```

but I would like to be able to resolve the issue at the "development" stage and not in my "staging" env.  I'm wondering if perhaps I have some setting in either dev to ignore this warning?  Both php.ini have the same:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

The development env is:

- Windows 8
- IIS 8.0
- PHP 5.4.15
- SQL Server 2008

Stage Env:

- Windows Server 2008
- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.4.15
- SQL Server 2008

Both environments connect to the same application_stage database on the same SQL Server 2008 database server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check php and IIS and optionally SQLServer or whatever data store you may be using default character set information it is likely they are different on the two servers

Comment: They both use the same data source.  It's a SQL Server 2008 database server.  They both connect to the same application_stage database.

Answer (score -1):

Could you show your php `array()`. Your problem might be in a value in your array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is in the value, but that's not the issue.  The exact same value gets pulled from the exact same data source.  The issue is that I only get the Warning on the Stage env, but not on the Dev env.